# MySQL: "Adding/Substracting strings in dialect 3" - error when operating on numeric fields?

Tags: mysql, sum, numeric, libreoffice-base

I have a `Service` table and a `Payments` table. I want my clients to be able to pay for one service with multiple payments, but when I try to create a form for making a payment, I'm unable to make a

```
"ServiceA"."Cost" - SUM("Payment"."Amount")
```

`substraction` in my `SELECT` query that would show the amount left to pay. I'm being told *`Strings cannot be added or subtracted in dialect 3`* even though all the relevant fields are Numeric, with the same amount of decimal points and everything...

Any idea on what I might be doing wrong?

EDIT:
More details. The relevant tables are actually as follows:
`ServiceA`, `ServiceB`, `ServiceC`, `ServiceD` all have a numeric field `Cost`. Their primary keys are actually foreign keys - they are all tied to an `auto_increment BIGINT` field in a table `For`. This is for the purpose of giving them `auto_incrementing`, yet non-repeating IDs.

There's a table `PS` (stands for `Payment-Service`) functions as a intermediate table for a multi-multi relationship. It has two foreign keys - one from `Payments` and one from `For`. This gives me the option to have multiple payments for one service or to have one payment cover multiple services.

Additionally, every `Service` table has a field referencing the ID of the client from "Clients".

In my `SELECT`, I try to do the following:

```
SELECT "Clients"."Name" || ': ' || "ServiceA"."Name" || ' for ' || "ServiceA"."Cost" - SUM("Payments"."Amount") AS "To-Pay", "ID-Name" AS "ID"
FROM "ServiceA"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Clients" ON "ServiceA"."Client" = "Clients"."ID-Client"
INNER JOIN "For" ON "ServiceA"."Id-ServA" = "For"."ID"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "PS" ON "For"."ID" = "PS"."For"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Payments" ON "PS"."Payment" = "Payments"."For"
GROUP BY "To-Pay, "ID"
HAVING "PS"."Payment" IS NULL OR **SUM("Payments"."Amount") < "ServiceA"."Cost"
UNION ALL
(like the above but with other "Service" tables)
ORDER BY "To-Pay"
```

This is for a dropdown list in a `Create Payment` form. It seems the problematic parts are the ones in bold.

Comment: can I suggest you to show us the table structure for the relevant tables, the attempted query and the error you get? Even if you are told something you'd better try it first, no?

Comment: Added more details to the question

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this

```
"ServiceA"."Cost" - SUM("Payment"."Amount")
```

to this

```
`ServiceA`.`Cost` - SUM(`Payment`.`Amount`)
```

Or cast it to a specific type

```
CAST("ServiceA"."Cost" AS DECIMAL(12,2)) - CAST(SUM("Payment"."Amount") AS DECIMAL(12,2));
```

Comment: No, Libre Office uses the " quotation marks for the names of database elements and the single ' ones for added strings if any. This is not the problem here.

Comment: Okay cool, you can try to cast it to a specific type like in the updated answer.

Comment: Didn't help. I've gone and changed the field types in all the relevant tables to DECIMAL (they were NUMERIC prior), but even then it still shows that "strings" can't be added or subtracted.